# How do I use SquishIt with a source that is not a valid virtual path

Tags: model-view-controller, cdn, squishit

I want to squish a whole bunch of stuff together from various sources around my local network
When I run the following code I get the error 'http://cdn.mydomain.org/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js' is not a valid virtual path ehich is fair enough, because it isn't

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(
 SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.JavaScript()
 .Add("http://cdn.mydomain.org/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js")
 .Add("~/Scripts/MyTrivialPlugin.js")
 .ForceRelease()
 .Render("~/Scripts/combined_#.js"))
```

Is there an option in SquishIt or any other 'squisher' that will take uri's for arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use a remote resource there is AddRemote, which expects the following, a localPath when debugging and a remotePath when in release. As you are forcing release, it'll always use your remotePath.